# Insert data in SQL Server database from excel using HTTP Post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vba, http-post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert data in SQL Server database from excel using HTTP Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362657/insert-data-in-sql-server-database-from-excel-using-http-post)

How can I insert data in SQL Server database from Excel using an HTTP Post to a C# ASP.NET project?

Lets say the URL is: http://testingHttpPost/ and I want to insert data from Cells A2 and B2 into "StudentTable" in Columns "StudentId" and "StudentAge" respectively when I click "Insert" Button in Excel.

I have an ActionResult method "InsertStudent" in Student Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can run c# code from a button in this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2009/10/02/excel-how-to-run-c-code-behind-with-a-click-of-a-button-on-a-worksheet-without-vba-code.aspx

In your c# code you can read values from the excel sheet and call the web service