# Insert data in SQL Server database from excel using HTTP Post

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, entity-framework, http-post

I want to insert data into SQL Server database when I click "Insert" button in excel.

The data is in Cells A2 and B2 and here is the code behind the "Insert" button in excel:

```
Dim HttpReq As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

HttpReq.Open "POST", "http://localhost:11121/Student/Insert/", False

HttpReq.Send "jsmith112"
```

Here is my code for the Controller action in VS:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Insert(string id)
    {

        try
        {

            student.AddToStudents(id);
            student.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

This doesn't seem to be working, could anyone guide me into finishing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's not working?  Is it throwing an error?  Is it even hitting your insert method? Where is the failure occurring?

Comment: You're trying to do an HTTPPost *to* SQL Server?  Is that even kosher?

Comment: He's doing an HTTP POST to an ASP.NET MVC web service, which is in turn using EF to update the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the POST to

```
"http://localhost:11121/Student/Insert/" + id
```

and then map the route

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "InsertStudent",
        "Student/Insert/{id}",
        new { controller = "Student", action = "Insert", id = "" }
    );
```

and then in your controller you can check if id is empty, if not then make a new user

also, sometimes I do things like this

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Resource",
        "{resource}/{operation}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Resource", action = "Index", resource = "", operation = "" id = "" }
    );
```

and then you could parse out what the things are..

as a side note and if you were making more end points for your service, you might consider using GET, POST, PUT, DELETE instead of actually having "Insert" in the URI. REST.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your controller action would see the data in this case.  It has no way of knowing that the 'jsmith112' you sent should correspond to the string id parameter.  Inside of your controller action, use the Request.InputStream object to grab the posted data and send that into the database.

A better way to do this would be to either send it through as url-encoded form data (so the post body would be 'id=jsmith112'), or to change the request to a GET (or a PUT, if you want to be properly RESTful) and hit this URL:

```
http://localhost:11121/Student/Insert/jsmith112
```

In that case it should be picked up by the string id parameter.

Also, put a breakpoint inside the controller action to be sure you're actually hitting it, then use the debugger to verify your web service has the data it needs.

Comment: Thanks for helping Evan,

So now my code behind "Insert" button in Excel is:

Dim HttpReq As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

HttpReq.Open "POST", "http://localhost:11121/Student/Insert/", False

HttpReq.Send "id=jsmith112"

How would I use the Request.InputStream to grab the posted data and insert it in Database?

Comment: In this case you're treating it as form data, so it should appear as a member of the Request.Form collection.  You may have to use HttpReq.SetRequestHeader to tell it to set the Content-Type header to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: Thanks! again. Now I am able to post the data from Excel to ASP.NET MVC web service. Here is My code for that:

Sub SendData()
Dim HttpReq As Object, url As String
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
url = "http://localhost:11121/Student/PostData/"
HttpReq.Open "POST", url, False
HttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
HttpReq.Send "Student=jsmith112"
Debug.Print HttpReq.ResponseText
End Sub

Now, I Want to have a ControllerAction "Insert" That will Insert posted data in SQLServer Database. What do I need to do to controller action for this?

Comment: You've already given a controller action above.  Is the code not hitting it?  Can you debug into the controller action?

Comment: I get an error on following line: "student.AddToStudents(id);"
error message:
Error: The best overloaded method match for 'STU.Models.StudentEntities.AddToStudent(STU.MODELS.Student)' has some invalid arguments.
Is it because I am passing a string inside of "AddToStudent" and not an "Entity"?