# How to pass a parameter from excel post to a controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, http-post, vba

How Can I pass a posted parameter to a controller action? Cant pass it in URL as the parameter is huge: Here is my Code from excel which I use to post the parameter:

```
Sub PostDataTest()
Dim PostData As String
Dim Comments As String
Dim PostDataURL As Srting

PostDataURL = "http://localhost:11121/InsertData/TestData/"

Comments = Me.Comments.Value

    Set httpReq = New MSXML2.xmlhttp

    httpReq.Open "POST", PostDataURL, False

    httpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    PostData = "Comments=" & Comments

    httpReq.send PostData
     PostData = ""
    Set httpReq = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here is my controller Action: I cannot pass "Comments" in URL as it is very long
Is there any other way to passing this variable to the below controller action?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestData(string Comments)
{
    TestData.Comments = Comments;
    DataContext.InsertTestData(TestData);      
}
```

Comment: So, this doesn't work? How doesn't it work? POSTing doesn't put the parameter in the URL, the data is hidden in the request instead.

Comment: @Cory How would I retrieve that data in a controller action? In this case "Comments"

Answer (score 2):

Your POST data should be in "key = value" format.

Where you have

```
PostData = Comments
```

Should probably be

```
PostData = "Comments=" & Comments
```

Otherwise the POST data in the request for the controller action could be empty or MVC might not be able to automagically bind the value to the `Comments` parameter in your action method.

See the following post(s) for reference:

- [Insert data in SQL Server database from excel using HTTP Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362657/insert-data-in-sql-server-database-from-excel-using-http-post)

If the binding to `Comments` isn't working, you can try to pull the value out of the request by changing your action definition to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestData(FormCollection form)
{
    TestData.Comments = form["Comments"];
    DataContext.InsertTestData(TestData);      
}
```

Comment: And how would I retrieve value from "Comments" in my controller action?

Comment: @user793468: I'm not sure what you're asking: the value would already be bound to the `Comments` string parameter in your action; i.e. your action method would stay exactly the way you have it in your post.

Comment: Passing "Comments" in URL is not possible as comments string is very huge. How I have it in my code above is by passing "Comments" as a parameter via URL.

Comment: @user793468: parameters are only passed on in the URL for GET requests. Your code uses a POST request, which embeds the `Comments` in the request header, which can be any size you want.

Comment: ok, I tried the above method, and I get a "String reference not set to an instance of a String" error, I debugged and "Comments" is null in my controller action. I updated my controller action above.

Comment: Sorry, Updated my Post to your suggestion. but get: String reference not set to an instance of a String

Comment: @user793468: I updated my answer with something else you can try. You can inspect the keys of the `FormCollection` with `form.AllKeys` to see if there is even a `Comments` key at all.

Comment: I am posting "Comments" from Excel, Its not from HTML form.

Comment: Tried the form collection approach, still get the same error: String reference not set to an instance of a String